# How to link mat-progress bar with project id from mat-table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I have a Job Execution screen which displays list of Jobs and their status.
I want to create an Indeterminate mat-progress bar which will appear for Jobs which are executing and when the status of Job changes to stop or complete it should disappear.
I have created a progress bar but I cannot link it to mat-table id or status.
HTML Code:

```
<div class="main-content">
<mat-toolbar>
    <mat-progress-bar
        mode="indeterminate"
        class="mat-progress-bar"
        color="primary"
    >
    </mat-progress-bar>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="stop_exec_job(element)"
        matTooltip="Stop Executing the Job"
    >
        <!-- Edit icon for row -->
        <i class="material-icons" style="color:red"> stop </i>
    </button>
</mat-toolbar>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h5 class="title">Job Execution Stats</h5>
    </div>

    <mat-table [dataSource]="jobExecutionStat">
        <!-- Id Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.id }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="exec_date">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                Execution Date
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
                >{{ element.exec_date }}
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Weight Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="curr_time_period">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                Current Time Period
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
                >{{ element.curr_time_period }}
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Symbol Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="prev_time_period">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                Previous Time Period
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
                >{{ element.prev_time_period }}
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
                >{{ element.status }}
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index = index">
                <button
                    mat-icon-button
                    (click)="stop_exec_job(element)"
                    matTooltip="Stop Executing the Job"
                    [disabled]="element.status == 'Completed'"
                >
                    <!-- Edit icon for row -->
                    <i class="material-icons" style="color:red"> stop </i>
                </button>
                <!-- Delete icon for row -->
                <button
                    mat-icon-button
                    (click)="re_run_job(element)"
                    matTooltip="Re-Run the Job"
                    [disabled]="
                        element.status == 'Running' ||
                        element.status == 'Pending'
                    "
                >
                    <i class="material-icons" style="color:green">
                        cached
                    </i>
                </button>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row
            *matHeaderRowDef="jobExecStatDisplayedColumns"
        ></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: jobExecStatDisplayedColumns">
        </mat-row>
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

Typescript Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MatTableDataSource } from "@angular/material";
import { GlobalAppSateService } from "../../services/globalAppSate.service";
import { DataService } from "../../services/data.service";
import { SnakBarComponent } from "../custom-components/snak-bar/snak- 
bar.component";
@Component({
selector: "app-job-execution-screen",
templateUrl: "./job-execution-screen.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./job-execution-screen.component.scss"]
})
export class JobExecutionScreenComponent implements OnInit {

jobExecStatDisplayedColumns = [
    "id",
    "exec_date",
    "prev_time_period",
    "curr_time_period",
    "status",
    "actions"
];

jobExecutionStat = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);
constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    public globalAppSateService: GlobalAppSateService,
    private snakbar: SnakBarComponent
) {}
ngOnInit() {
    const project = JSON.parse(this.dataService.getObject("project"));
    if (project != null) {
        this.globalAppSateService.onMessage(project);
    }
}

stop_exec_job(element) {
    if(element.status == 'Running') {
        this.snakbar.statusBar('Job Execution Stopped','Sucess');

    }
}
re_run_job(element) {
    if(element.status == 'Completed') {
        this.snakbar.statusBar('Job Execution Started','Sucess');

    }
}
}
const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
{
    id: 1,
    exec_date: "17-01-2016",
    prev_time_period: "2016-04,2016-05,2016-06",
    curr_time_period: "2016-08",
    status: "Completed"
},
{
    id: 2,
    exec_date: "17-01-2017",
    prev_time_period: "2017-04,2017-05,2017-06",
    curr_time_period: "2017-08",
    status: "Running"
},
{
    id: 3,
    exec_date: "27-07-2017",
    prev_time_period: "2017-45,2017-46,2017-47",
    curr_time_period: "2018-01,2018-02",
    status: "Pending"
},
{
    id: 4,
    exec_date: "17-10-2018",
    prev_time_period: "2017-30,2017-31,2017-32",
    curr_time_period: "2018-01,2018-02",
    status: "Completed"
},
{
    id: 5,
    exec_date: "21-01-2018",
    prev_time_period: "2016-01,2016-02,2016-03,2016-04",
    curr_time_period: "2016-52",
    status: "Pending"
},
{
    id: 6,
    exec_date: "17-01-2018",
    prev_time_period: "2017-31,2017-32,2017-33,2017-34",
    curr_time_period: "2017-52",
    status: "Running"
}
];
export interface Element {
id: number;
exec_date: string;
prev_time_period: string;
curr_time_period: string;
status: string;
}
```

[Link for stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-progressbar-autocomplete-bavr9a)

Answer (score 1):

Stop button that is placed next to Job Name is working because the `element` variable is valid(i.e. inside mat-table tag).

But it's not working for Stop button next to Progress bar because the `element` variable is undefined/not valid(i.e. Outside of mat-table tag). That's why its giving error like 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined.'